# google.script.run is returning undefined. How do I fix it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get an array from a spreadsheet and use it to populate a dropdown. Here is my code

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {

  var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index'); 

return page.evaluate()

}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getArrayList(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1EjRFAYiMBw5BuNhFJRUVG4MpUjIIy8Oey5JLyiYxj3c");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Nomes");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var array = [];

  for each (var item in values){
    array.push(item[0]);
  }

  return array

}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?!= include('jQuery'); ?>

  <div class="demo" >

      <form id="myForm">
        <select id="selectNumber">
          <option>Choose a number</option>
        </select>
      </form>

<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>

    </div>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
        var options = google.script.run.getArrayList();
        console.log(options);

        $('#selectNumber').empty();
        $.each(options, function(i, p) {
            $('#selectNumber').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
        });

</script>
```

**jQuery.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If instead of using `var options = google.script.run.getArrayList();` on the JavaScript.html file, I pass a literal array `var options = ["1","2","3"];` my code works like a charm.

I know that the problem is that `google.script.run` is returning `Undefined`, but I don´t know what I´m doing wrong. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this useful for you?

google.script.run.function() doesn't return values. So `options` of `var options = google.script.run.getArrayList();` is `Undefined`. Use [withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) to get the returned values from `getArrayList()`. Below is the updated `JavaScript.html`.

```
<script>
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(sample).getArrayList();

        function sample(options) {
            $('#selectNumber').empty();
            $.each(options, function(i, p) {
                $('#selectNumber').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Excelent! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

values is an array of arrays.  To get all of the data you need to do something like:

```
var a=[];
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
{
  for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++)
  {
     a.push(values[i][j]);
}
}
```

or just return values