# google.script.run.function() returning null

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

On a google sheet, I have a sidebar form allowing user to add infos in another sheet.
I have to give an ID to each line so when a user add one, generate a new id.

example :
the sidebar form has two inputs : criterion number (int) and criterion (text). when a user add these inputs, I want to put them in a sheet with 3 columns : A = ID, B = criterion number and C = criterion.
To generate the ID, I created a creeID() function on the server side (this function checks the last ID in the sheet and generate the next ID, works well when tested) and I have to call it when the user add a  line ("ajouter" button) in order to get a tab with this format `[ID, criterion number, criterion]` and to push this tab in the sheet with `appendRow()`

I thought I could use google script run with `.withSuccessHandler()` like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331964/google-script-run-is-returning-undefined-how-do-i-fix-it) and I tried something based on @Tanaike's help and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRyxJZRlrWM).

Everything seems to work fine except that `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {alert("preuve ajoutée")}).creeID()` returns `null`

here is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      ...
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Indicateur</p>
    <input type="number" name="indicateur" id="indic" value="" min = "1" max = "32">
    <p>Preuve</p>
    <input type="text" name="preuve" id="preuve">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Ajouter" onclick="ajouter()">
    <span class="annuler" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Annuler</span>

    <script>
      function ajouter() {
        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#indic, #preuve');
        let tab = [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {alert("preuve ajoutée")}).creeID()];
        

        // Récupération des valeurs
        for (const input of inputs) {
          tab.push(input.value);
        }

        // Si tous les champs sont vides
        if (tab.join('') == '') {
          alert('Le formulaire est vide !');
          return;
        }

        // Vider les champs
        inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');

        // Envoi dans la feuille
        google.script.run.ajouterLigne(tab);
      }
  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the javascript code :

```
function ajouterLigne(tab) {
  const PREUVES = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PREUVES");
  console.log(tab)
  PREUVES.appendRow(tab);
}

function creeID() {
  const SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PREUVES");
  let lastRow = SHEET.getLastRow();
  let lastIdRange = SHEET.getRange(lastRow, 1);
  let lastId = lastIdRange.getValue(); 
  let newId;

  if (lastId == "ID") {
    newId = 1;
  } else {
    newId = lastId + 1;
  };

  return(newId)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of your script, `google.script.run.creeID()` returns no value. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. From `maybe I should use .withSuccessHandler() like said here but I don't know how.`, how about using `withSuccessHandler()` as follows?

In this case, please modify `ajouter()` of your Javascript as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function ajouter() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(tab => {
    tab = [tab];
    for (const input of inputs) {
      tab.push(input.value);
    }
    if (tab.join('') == '') {
      alert('Le formulaire est vide !');
      return;
    }
    inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');
    google.script.run.ajouterLigne(tab);
  }).creeID();
}
```

- In this modification, when a button is clicked, a value of `tab` is retrieved and the values of `tab` and the inputted values are appended to the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work, I need creeID() to return a value (id) and to put it in tab at the first index. With your solution, only the user input are in tab

Comment: @mthgn Thank you for replying. About `With your solution, only the user input are in tab`, my proposed modification is from your showing script for explaining your question of `I should use .withSuccessHandler() like said here but I don't know how.`. I apologize for this. About `but it doesn't seem to work, I need creeID() to return a value (id) and to put it in tab at the first index.`, I guess that this might be your actual expected result. But, I cannot understand it. So, can you provide the detail of your actual expected result? From this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: @mthgn I would like to support you. So, if you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?

Comment: thank you for your help and sorry for the delay... I edited the question, Hope it will help you understand what I need.

Comment: @mthgn Thank you for replying. From your reply and updated question, I understood that you added one more question. In your question, the following 2 questions are included. 1. You want to remove the issue of `google.script.run.function() returning null`. 2. You want to achieve `example :`. When I saw `example :`, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your additional question, I have the following 3 questions. I would like to think of a solution by correctly understand your additional question.

Comment: @mthgn 1. About `the sidebar form has to inputs : criterion number (int) and criterion (text).`, in your showing HTML, 2 text inputs are existing. Is your actual HTML different from your showing HTML? 2. About `when a user add these inputs, I want to put them in another sheet with 3 columns : ID, criterion number and criterion.`, I cannot know where the columns `ID, criterion number and criterion` are put in the Spreadsheet. 3. I cannot understand `I have to run it on the client side in order to have a tab with this format [ID, criterion number, criterion]`. Can I ask you the detail of it?

Comment: thank you again for your help and don't worry for your English skills, mine are not so good. I edited the question based on your questions. columns are A,B and C in the spreadsheet and the only remaining problem is that `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {alert("preuve ajoutée")}).creeID()` returns `null`

Comment: @mthgn Thank you for replying and updating the question. From your updated question, you input a number and a string to the 2 input tags, and you want to retrieve the next ID number and want to append the value like `["newIDNumber", "indicateur", "preuve"]` to "PREUVES" sheet. If my understanding is correct, when your updated script is used, please modify my proposed script as follows. From `const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');` to `const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#indic, #preuve');`. By this, I think that your goal is achieved.

Comment: As you can see in my code everything is fine with `const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#indic, #preuve');` the problem is that may tab is `[null, input1, input2]` instead of `[ID, input1, input2]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253966/discussion-between-mthgn-and-tanaike).